# How do I expand/collapse tree node when clicking on the title?

Tags: oracle-apex

My tree has no links (#) on the folder title and some functions with links under the folder. I want to expand/collpase folder when user clicks on the title. Out of the box tree displays small arrow for the folder to expand/collpase it.

Thanks
Kishore

Comment: Do you still need help with this? What version of APEX are you using? Setting up an example of your problem on apex.oracle.com and providing developed credentials is always helps (just be sure there's nothing sensitive in there).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest method is to set a Static ID for your tree region (e.g. mytree).
Then you need to invoke the click event on span.a-TreeView-toggle HTML item when you click on the title of a folder item in the tree.

The following JavaScript code can be used in a Dynamic Action that fires on Page Load:

```
$('#mytree div.a-TreeView-content').click(function(){
$(this).prev('span.a-TreeView-toggle').click();
});
```